# Which textbooks on College Algebra, Trigonometry, Pre-calculus, Calculus, Linear Algebra, ODE are written by world-class mathematicians?

Tags: undergraduate-education, calculus, textbooks, trigonometry, precalculus

For example, [Trigonometry](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780817639143) was written by Wolf-Prize winner [Israel Gelfand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Gelfand), one of the top mathematicians in the 20th century. I am wondering if other world-class mathematicians have written textbooks on some elementary undergraduate courses such as College Algebra, Trigonometry, Pre-calculus, Calculus, Linear Algebra, ODE as I would love my students to read textbooks written by the best mathematicians.

Comment: So you will teach them calculus using Courant and John?  Seriously, Gelfand was unusual in this way: taking the time to do elementary textbooks.  But before adopting Galfand for your students, take a look at it to see whether it is at the right level for them.

Comment: *textbooks written by the best mathematicians* --- It seems to me that two often different attributes are being conflated here. Also, the textbook's audience is a crucial factor (e.g. [Harvard's Math 55](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_55) vs. [these courses](https://www.google.com/search?q=remedial+mathematics)). That said, despite what you might think from Gelfond's name, the analogy "Gelfond's book to trigonometry $::$ Courant/John's book to calculus" (or any of the other well known substitutions one might make for "Courant/John $:$ calculus")  is far from being very accurate.

Comment: @Dan Fox: Typo on my part.

Comment: David Mumford appears among the list of "producers" of the Hughes-Hallett Mutlivariable Calculus book.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold for this book, I am surprised how many authors there are and I am not sure how much Mumford has contributed to the book.

Comment: neither do I know, but Mumford writes some things about it [here](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/beyond/education.html)

Comment: Terence tao has written many books, one on problem solving, and other two books on undergraduate analysis.He also has a book on measure theory. Halmos has also written many books

Comment: Are you assuming that textbooks written by world-class mathematicians will be *good* textbooks? To quote an acquaintance of Serge Lang's, "We all knew he wrote terrible books, but we loved him anyway."

Comment: @DanielR.Collins, I use Lang's book for my calculus courses and I think his books are great. Surely some great books are written by average mathematicians; but the point of my question is, I want to have my students read textbooks written by most successful mathematicians instead of average college professors.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Actually, it was the accepted practice in Russia when big names in math tackled grade school education, because after all these would be the students these profs would have to deal with in a uni. Not always it worked well. For example, prof [Kolmogorov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Kolmogorov) was pulled into math reform, the Soviet New Math, and then became the locomotive of the reform, which ultimately failed, mostly because of poor geometry textbooks, which Kolmogorov did not author. No wonder the no-nonsense century-old Kiselev's textbook became fashionable again.

Comment: BTW, [Kiselev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrei_Petrovich_Kiselyov) was not a "world-class mathematician", he only obtained a "degree that allowed him to teach in a Gymnasium". But he spent years licking out his textbooks, so they remained in use well into 1950s, despite "having some logical gaps, which were beyond understanding of an ordinary student." After the Soviet New Math school reform failed, his textbooks, particularly planimetry and stereometry, became popular again.

Comment: There is no mathematical subject called "college algebra". That is a term invented by the publishing industry to make students feel that they're studying a more advanced topic than what is normally taught in secondary school.

Comment: Excellent educator/ teacher versus excellent mathematician?
I think there's an incredible distinction between A. being an excellent mathematician- informally defined as one who can do math at a very high level., prove difficult theorems, etc.  Contrast this with being an excellent educator.  An excellent educator must also be aware of audience, common pitfalls learning a specific subject, truly care for his students, etc.
Although, the two categories certainly overlap, I'm sure there are many

Comment: @MichaelHardy what's a better name?  Algebra?- nope, for many professors and math majors Algebra includes Abstract algebra.  Yes, college algebra is often a repeat of Algebra II concepts, but it's a perfectly suitable textbook title and/or course description.  No, need to disparage those who didn't grasp it or forgot it since the first time around.

Comment: @nickalh : I don't want to disparage anybody, but I don't think we should mislead people in order to sell more books.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Books about middle school algebra and trigonometry written by someone like Gelfand are rare (I don't know other examples; for example V.I. Arnold's books nomially for children are aimed at very special children, their author's claims to the contrary), but there are many undergraduate textbooks written by superb mathematicians. I list below some that occur to me now. However, most of those I list are aimed at a level probably a bit above that which interests the OP.

Vladimir Arnold wrote an excellent textbook on ordinary differential equations.

Peter Lax wrote a (moderately advanced) book on linear algebra.

Serge Lang wrote textbooks on calculus, linear algebra, complex analysis, and some other undergraduate subjects. I don't particularly like his books, but that is a different matter.

Cliff Taubes wrote a book called "Modeling differential equations in biology".

While not exactly a textbook, the book of Persi Diaconis and Brian Skyrmes called "Ten great ideas about chance" is an excellent introduction to probabilistic thinking directed at a general undergraduate audience.

Marcel Berger wrote some textbooks directed at future math teachers that treat classical affine and projective geometry (they have been translated into English). They would be hard for a US educated audience.

Elias Stein has coauthored with Rami Shakarchi a series of books on real, complex, fourier, and functional analysis. The only one I've read is the book on Fourier analysis, and it is excellent and pedagogical, the book I always wished I had encountered as a student.

Yuri Manin wrote a linear algebra textbook (however, it is not afraid to discuss functors).

Comment: Thank you for this list! It is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This may not qualify, as it is a stretch to classify this as a "textbook."
It arose from a series of lecture Klein gave to high-school teachers.

> Klein, Felix. *Elementary Mathematics from an Advanced Standpoint: Geometry*. Transl. from the Third German Ed. by ER Hedrick and CA Noble. Dover, 1939.
>
> ---
>
> [image]

---

I love this (1939) opening "Gentlemen!" Preface sentence:

> "Gentlemen! The course of lectures which I now begin will be an
>   immediate continuation of, and supplement to, my course last Winter."

How times have changed!

I am less familiar with the content
of the other volumes:

> Klein, Felix. *Elementary mathematics from an advanced standpoint: Arithmetic, algebra, analysis*. Vol. 1. Courier Corporation, 2004.